# Changing the selected option in a dropdown menu and so cause an onchange event; javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Well, I have spent quite a while fiddling round with this with little progress. I have seen plenty of solution however, implementing them into my situation isn't working and I really don't know why.

I am trying to make some images change the selected value of a dropdown menu upon being clicked and so causing an onchange event on the dropdown menu to occur.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function parse_theme(input){
    var index = document.getElementById('themes').length; /* this bit is working fine */
    for(var i=0;i<=index;i++;){
       if(document.getElementById('themes').options[i].value == input){ /*error is here */
          document.getElementById('themes').selectedIndex = i;
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

And the html:

```
<select id="themes" style="display:none;" onchange="selectTheme()">
  <option value="default" selected="selected">default</option>
  <option value="ambiance">ambiance</option>
  <option value="cobalt">cobalt</option>
</select>

<img id="default" onclick="parse_theme(this.id)" src="images/default.png" width="10" height="10">
<img id="ambiance" onclick="parse_theme(this.id)" src="images/ambiance.png" width="10" height="10">
<img id="cobalt" onclick="parse_theme(this.id)" src="images/cobalt.png" width="10" height="10">
```

And I'm recieving "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

The onchange function works fine, when I simply have the dropdown menu however, I wanted it to be done through a sequence of images and have the images refer to the options in the list and have the list to be invisible.

Comment: You're not passing an ID in your line `document.getElementById.options[i].value`

Comment: Ah, sorry on the other one it did have the id in, but still didn't work

Comment: if your onchange function is named can you not call it from parse_theme?

Comment: I could of made this a lot simpler, yes. But, I've spent ages working on this alternative and I'm not risking going back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
for(var i=0;i<index;i++;){
```

You are probably failing for the last index of the loop since index value will be 3 you will loop for 0,1,2,3 instead of only 3 times

Comment: Ah, I could of sworn I tried that but, yes it is working now. It isn't causing the selectTheme() to run but is changing the selection in the drop down menu. Is there a reason why this is? I suppose I can always look into it thanks for your help. I always seem to overthink these errors.

Comment: Ok, and now it's entirely fixed. I simply put the setTheme() function inside the if statment of the parse_theme() function. So, it's all sorted now. thanks for everyones input.